# How do you change the rect of a group without changing the location of the objects in it?

Tags: livecode

I have a situation where I have a **group** with `lockLocation true` and I need to *resize* it and the all the objects within it recursively.

I have either problem A. or problem B.

**A.** If I set the rect of the group before its children then the children move so I can no longer use their rect as the basis for their calculated new rect.

**B**. If I set the rect of the children first then setting the rect of the parent group will move the children to the wrong position.

**Possible solution**
The only thing I can think of is to calculate an offset to subtract from the rect of the child objects and pass that to the recursive handler.

Comment: What I did with morph (http://mobgui.com/morph.php) was a first pass to record all the control rectangles then a second pass to resize everything in layer order - so the groups get done then the controls contained within them, but this time you know every control's previous rectangle for reference.  Maybe worth a try.

Comment: I'd like to avoid multiple iterations of the controls if possible because it's expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the offset method I was talking about. This works. As I said this is a recursive command so it is dispatched to the control with the owner's group offset. I'm looking at the other answers to see if I can optimise this some more or if your ideas are better.

```
command mAppScaleObject pScale,pGroupOffset
   local tRect,tScaledPoints,tPoints,tMargins,tControlIDs,tTabStops,tResizeGroup
   -- here groups complicate things because relocating them changes the rects of
   -- their child objects. Let groups resize around objects if they are unlocked.
   put the rect of the target into tRect
   repeat with X=1 to 4
      if X mod 2 = 0 then
         put round((pGroupOffset["Y"]+item X of tRect)*pScale) into item X of tRect
      else
         put round((pGroupOffset["X"]+item X of tRect)*pScale) into item X of tRect
      end if
   end repeat
   put word 1 of the target is "group" and the lockLocation of the target into tResizeGroup
   if tResizeGroup then
      add the left of the target-item 1 of tRect to pGroupOffset["X"]
      add the top of the target-item 2 of tRect to pGroupOffset["Y"]
   end if
   if word 1 of the target is not "group" or tResizeGroup then
      set the rect of the target to tRect
   end if
```

---

**EDIT**

I have resolved this issue and improved performance for setting lots of properties on objects inside groups at the engine level now with a new group property lockUpdates. It stops the group from being updated automatically when any child control is resized or moved while the lockUpdates is true.

https://github.com/runrev/livecode/commit/28a93bbf93e96b19662c77ae09fd57f611073bc5

Comment: I strongly advice against this solution. See my answer elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think you know enough about this solution to strongly advise against it.

Comment: Same to you, Monte. Also, maybe you should make sure that all info is in your questions before you post them.

Comment: I did not mention that I needed a solution that took into account rounding errors because I didn't need one.

Comment: Again, wrong information, Monte. Apparently, you don't know how to ask questions. Anyway, I'm out of here, because this is not the type of discussion one ought to have on this website.

Comment: ??? That's not wrong information... Perhaps you didn't even read the question because your answer is almost completely unrelated to it. The question is about the fact that moving the rect of a group will move the controls and it explicitly states that I am using the control rects as a basis for calculating the new rects. I'm just unsure why you would want to strongly advise against a solution that I've stated works then go on to provide a solution unrelated to the question then berate me for not asking the question you answered...

Answer (score 0):

What I did when I made a small iOS screenswap palette was to first scale all objects in the group, then buffer all locations of the controls in the group:

```
 repeat with i = 1 to the number of controls of pObject
    put the loc of control i of pObject into tArr[i]
 end repeat
```

Then scale the group and finally reset all controls:

```
if tArr is an array then
  repeat with i = 1 to the number of elements in tArr
     set the loc of control i of pObject to tArr[i]
  end repeat
end if
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'd like to avoid the extra iteration on the controls if possible because it's expensive. The offset method only iterates the controls once.

Answer (score 0):

Lock messages before attempting to resize the group rect - that will prevent the objects in the group from moving out from under you.

Comment: I'm not worried about resize control handlers at this stage. It's the fact that moving the rect of the group moves the child controls which means the rects of the child controls can no longer be used for the scaling calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the boundingRect of the group to true before resizing the child objects, and then setting the rect of the group to its full extents before disabling the boundingRect.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. Set the bounding rect to the current rect of the group, resize the child controls then set the rect of the group?

Comment: Yup.  If the boundingRect of the group is set to a specific rect value, the group should not resize when its objects are moved beyond its rect.

Comment: right, but how do you then set the rect of the group? If I'm not mistaken that will still change the loc of the child controls.

Comment: Set the boundingRect of the group to empty.

Comment: Hmm... I still don't get it. Is there any chance you could edit your answer with a brief script demonstrating scaling by 2 the rect of a group with lockLocation and one button in it. So that the button ends up at the correct location.

Comment: Is this for a custom control of some sort?  I'm not sure if this will work for you, but rather than fighting with the group and its contents, what I do in all my controls is to place a transparent graphic at the base level of the group -- what I call a "region" -- that keeps the group "expanded" and acts as anchor for all contained objects.  In my experience, when resizing a group, it's best to resize a *single* object within the group -- the region graphic -- to the group's new rect, and then move/scale everything else based on that graphic, NOT the group itself.

Comment: This is for a pixel density and aspect ratio independence framework for mobile so I'm not in control of the group contents. I often use the same technique for custom control resizeControl handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the original locations and rects of objects to determine the new locations and objects, you will make rounding errors and eventually all will go wrong. This is one of the reasons why the Geometry Manager is totally unreliable. I would therefore strongly advice against your solution, Monte.

Instead, I'd set the rects of all objects relative to the rects of the group, e.g. always with a 16 pixels margin. Probably, this solution doesn't allow for a general approach and that's why I always write my own scripts, which talk to the controls directly:

```
put the rect of grp 1 into myRect
add 16 to item 1 of myRect
add 16 to item 2 of myRect
subtract 16 from item 3 of myRect
subtract 16 from item 4 of myRecy
set the rect of fld 1 to myRect
-- etc
```

Comment: My scaling is only ever applied on the device using mobilePixelDensity so there's no rounding error issue.